# Convert Javascript date to shorter date time and also UTC

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, date, typescript

I have a JavaScript Date which I want to get it into SQL Server datetime field.

The JavaScript time sent over as

```
Fri Sep 15 2017 00:11:44 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)
```

I want it to be converted in javascript or in C#

1. I need the date to be like

   ```
   2017-09-15 23:47:01
   ```

OR perhaps

```
9/15/2017 11:47:01 PM
```

2. I need to also convert it to UTC ,  not sure if that is easier to do in javascript or in C#

Which type of format is my code even in?  "Fri Sep 15 .."  ??

For UTC I was seeing code like this

```
 var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();
```

( I am doing .net core web api,  with Angular 4 / Typescript)

Comment: I know it may seem trivial but working with dates and times is really hard, I recommend you leave it up to [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to handle this for you.  If you remove "(US Mountain Standard Time)" from the string, it should be pretty easy.

Comment: Here is a simple regex, that basically extracts the bit's of an ISOString -> `new Date('Fri Sep 15 2017 00:11:44 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)').toISOString().replace(/(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)$/,'$1 $2')`

Comment: But that creates  `2017-09-15T07:11:44.000Z`

Answer (score 0):

As Keith said, working with dates is really hard in javascript, especially considering very different implementations across the browsers. So I will second their opinion: just use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and leave everything to that library. It is really powerful. Using it you can get any date format you can possibly think of. To get "2017-09-15 23:47:01" all you need is the following (please pay attention that qualifiers are case sensitive!):

```
var fmt = moment(<your_js_date_if_you_have_it>).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

You can find all supported qualifiers [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Apart from formatting this library also allows you to do a lot of manipulations with the dates, compare them, translate dates from local to UTC time zone and back, etc.

Comment: I cannot use moment.js ...  sadly a security team rejects 99% of packages...    I've used it in the past.

Comment: Wow... Someone has even more restrictive security rules then me... Well, then the only viable option you have is to write something like moment.js yourself, but that's going to be a BIG pain - I've tried... :(